# Loading context from within a Jar

Tags: java, spring, jar, applicationcontext

I need some clarification; I have a jar that I built and inside of the jar it has a custom `application-context.xml` file that I need to load. I load the file within a class inside of the jar. When I am setting the url of this application-context.xml, is the directory specific to my jar's classpath, or still the project that is using the jar-'s classpath?

For example --

Jar's classpath:

```
src > main > META-INF > application-custom-context.xml
```

Project's classpath:

```
src > Libraries > myjar.jar > src > main > META-INF > application-custom-context.xml
```

I know these url's aren't accurate :P -- But, inside of my context creation, which directory structure would I follow. This is all theoretical. Somebody asked me this today, and I have no clue how to answer it. I would think that if you call a class from a jar, the classpath should be relative to the contents of that jar.. But, what I think is far from always right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "path" to the Spring context is relative to the classpath.  If the jar is included in your classpath (it's in web-inf/lib for example), then it would be treated just as if it was in your project (web-inf/classes).

In other words, if your context file is in "META-INF\spring\context.xml" inside your jar file, anyone who includes your jar file can reference it in the same manner.

Comment: I think I'm getting twisted in your words.. If I have a jar in which the app-context.xml file is located at META-INF/spring/app-context.xml and I add that jar to a project, what would the referenced url be? Simply if I was to be adding the xml using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("url").

Comment: new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/app-context.xml") or if you simply had it in the root of the jar file you could reference as "app-context.xml"